# Can you swap columns in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know if I can swap columns in excel, by swapping I don't mean only swapping contents of the column but column name also.

For example, I have empty excel with column names in order: A B C D E ....

new excel file:

[image]

Can I swap column A and D for example so order will be D B C A E ...

Please advice.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Use table headers instead. See [Change the column label? e.g.: change column "A" to column "Name"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21107976)

Comment: The column letters and row numbers refer to their position not their content.  Row 3 will always be whatever row is third, and column A will always be whatever column is first.